# Yoast breadcrumb URL shows category instead of the page

Tags: posts, categories, pages, breadcrumb

I have setup Yoast breadcrumbs in my category pages en posts inside that category page.

Category page: home/diensten/
Post page: home/diensten/support/

When I want to navigate back from the support post and click on 'diensten' the link navigates to:  home/category/diensten/ instead off: home/diensten/

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why is your category page home/diensten/? If you go to _Posts > Categories_ and click _View_ on one of the categories, what URL do you get?

Comment: Then is this the URL: http://meester-en-kuiper:8888/category/diensten/ but the slug is: diensten.

Comment: Which is what's in the breadcrumb, correct? So what is home/diensten/? Why do you expect that URL in the breadcrumb?

Comment: I expect that because /diensten/ is a page and inside diensten I have posts that being setup under the category: 'diensten',  So you have /diensten(page)/accountancy(posts). Going rewind and clicking in the breadrumb on diensten you must  go the page diensten with the overall products.

Comment: Posts don't belong to pages. Posts belong to categories. It sounds like you've created a redundant page that does the same thing as the category archive that's generated automatically. It doesn't sound at all reasonable to me to expect WordPress to know that you were doing this. Why aren't you using category/diensten?

Comment: Yes I have created several categories like 'diensten' and in a categorie I have specific posts. On the 'page' diensten I've setup links to these posts in the category 'diensten'. So clicking on a post you see in the breadcrumb where you are, but you expect when you click on 'diensen' to go back to the overall page with diensten where I linked to all the posts from 'diensten'. 
Thanks

Comment: Why did you create a page for each category? You don’t need to create a page to list posts in a category. One is created for you at /category/diensten.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, yes that is the logic structure of a custom post on a specific category right?  But then still the question why the breadcrumb shows: /category/teamleden/member instead of  /teamleden/member. /teamleden/ is the overall page but not the a post type but a custom build page.

Comment: I fixed this issue with:
`add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'yoast_seo_breadcrumb_append_link' );
function yoast_seo_breadcrumb_append_link( $links ) {
    global $post;
 if ( is_single( array( 216, 212, 206, 205, 327, 215, 536, 535 ) ) ){
        $breadcrumb[] = array(
            'url' => site_url( '/diensten/'),
            'text' => 'diensten', 
        );
      array_splice( $links, 1, -2, $breadcrumb );
    }
return $links;`